# No scalar summary tags were found

Tags: tensorflow

I used TensorFlow.

Python Program was run on jupyter.

And tensorboard was run.

`mkdir log
tensorboard --logdir=./log`

But TensorBoard sayed 'No scalar summary tags were found.'.

Why ?

Solution to I want to know.

OS: Windows 10 ( Docker Quickstart Terminal )

Answer (score 0):

The `--logdir` refers to the directory into which your tensorflow `SummaryWriters` wrote log data as your model was run. By running `mkdir` I'm assuming that that dir is empty when you run tensorboard. Basically, you need to find the directory that has the summaries that were written by your python code.

Can refer here for more detailed info:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html

Hope that helps.